# Создание заказа в WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Ребята, помогите! Я уже почти в отчаянии. Впервый подгоняю сайт под woo и нужно сделать создание заказа. Это должно происходить не со страницы чекаут и поэтому код тоже пишу свой.
Я, естественно, перед тем, как создавать полноценный код, чтобы это всё работало с кнопки решил сделать макет того, как создаю заказ, взял фул готовый код с сайта чела, у которого много всего по woo и wp:

```
do_action('true_create_order');

function true_create_order() {

// Начинаем с того, что создаём заказ, вполне логично
$order = wc_create_order();

// Теперь давайте разберёмся с платёжным/адресом доставки покупателя
$address = array(
'first_name' => 'Миша',
'last_name' => 'Рудрастых',
'company' => 'Студия Миши Рудрастых',
'email' => 'no-reply@misha.agency',
'phone' => '123-123-123',
'address_1' => 'Большой пр. ПС',
'address_2' => '100',
'city' => 'Санкт-Петербург',
'state' => 'Санкт-Петербург',
'postcode' => '191033',
'country' => 'RU'
);

// Теперь можем задать этот адрес как платёжный
$order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
// И как адрес доставки
$order->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );
// Неплохо бы добавить пару товаров в заказ
$product_id = 27; // Допустим ID товара 37
$product_qty = 1; // 1 единица товара будет норм
$order->add_product( wc_get_product( $product_id ), $product_qty );
// Установим платёжный метод, например пусть это будет оплата наличными при получении
$payment_gateways = WC()->payment_gateways->payment_gateways();
if( ! empty( $payment_gateways[ 'cod' ] ) ) {
$order->set_payment_method( $payment_gateways[ 'cod' ] );
}
// Добавляем доставку
$item = new WC_Order_Item_Shipping();
$item->set_method_title( "Доставочка" ); // название
$item->set_method_id( "flat_rate:14" ); // указываем ID существующего способа доставки
$item->set_total( 5 ); // стоимость доставки (необязательно)
$order->add_item( $item );
// Пересчитываем заказ
$order->calculate_totals();
// Устанавливаем нужный нам статус
// $order->set_status( 'completed' );
// $order->save();
//$order->update_status( 'completed' );
// Можно добавить заметку в заказ
$order->add_order_note( 'Заказ создан динамически.' );
}
```

И этот код не работает. Если разкомментировать update_status, то код просто выбивает ошибка а так просто ничего не происходит.

Возможно не в нужное время пытаюсь использовать эту функцию, хз короче, не работает. В эту же копилку могу отметить, что при переходе в корзину, аккаунт или чекаут, то открывается индекс и выбивает ошибку, что страница с таким айди не найдена. Через mySQL смотрел и видел, что корзина есть и с правильным айди, но он всё равно капризничает...

Я перечитал уже тонну форумов и подобного, но адекватного объяснения не нашёл. Пытался создавать woocommerce.php и там всё прописывать, в functions.php, без толку. Нашёл, что нужно скопировать директорию woo в тему и переименовать её, но эффекта тоже 0. Даже в логи опенсервера лазил.

Но как только включаю стандартную тему по типу 2021 то всё начинает работать. И какбы я понимаю, что я скорее всего какой-то обязательный кусок кода для Woo не прописал просто, но какой...
Да, сам по себе ву подключил

Может кто знает, в чём может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо